# What are Feltrite Crystals traded for in Rage?

Tags: rage

In *RAGE*, Fellix Hagar tells me that `Feltrite Crystals` are very rare and only to trade them for something I really want. They can be sold to a merchant for $25 each. Can they be traded for anything at all in the game, or should I just sell them immediately?

Comment: No definitive answer on this yet, but they are marked with a $ which seems to indicate junk. Not 100% through the story though.

Comment: @DoozerBlake Items with a $ mean that they are not directly usable in the inventory/quick slot nor are they used in a recipe. The `Lock Grinder` would seem to prove this. Its only usable on a locked door, but it has a $ sign.

Comment: The name amused me - I always read it in my head as "felt right"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can trade 20 of them to Jacob, he's in the bar in Wellspring, for a defib upgrade (which means you can die one more time before a game over)

There is virtually unlimited Feltrite in the game so selling a few doesn't matter. driving around the wasteland will occasionally activate missions automatically. One of the missions  requires you to collect 7 falling Feltrites, afterwhich you keep all 7. I just recently came across another one where it was "collect as many as you can in the time given" - I got a whopping 15.

Note that the [Feltrite shower events (Feltrite tempests/storms) are not unlimited, but scripted](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Feltrite_Tempest). There are 3. The first two will allow you to get up to 7 each. The third one will allow you to gain up to 20.

As far as any other use outside that one upgrade, I don't know of any.

Comment: I just got that upgrade. Does anyone know of any others?

Comment: The defibrillator uprgrade is for when you die and you can use that technique to revive yourself instantly, With the upgrade, you can do it twice without dying.

Comment: Do you mean there is another Defibrilator update except the one you get from the Dead City mission and built in by Kvasir? Like I upgrade my Defib 2 times and charge even faster? Or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

You can get an awesome upgrade later on for 20 crystals. Don't make the same mistake I did, save at least 20.

Comment: Well that's not what I want to hear!

Comment: Can you give more details on what the awesome upgrade is?  You can use the spoiler text if you want to give people the option of not reading the details.  Just put ">!" in front of your text.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, the "awesome upgrade" he is talking about allows you to charge up your defibs faster. If you'll notice, when you use a defib, it takes appx 5 minutes (not exactly sure) to recharge ONE defib slot.

Comment: The upgrade cuts a minute off your defib recharge time.